# Geoserver support for WKB spatialdata

Tags: geoserver, sql-server-spatial, well-known-binary

I use SQL Server (2012 sp3) DB with Geoserver and i noticed that Geoserver likes to call SQL like

```
SELECT ... geom.STAsBinary() FROM (geoserver sql view) WHERE geom.filter(...)
```

In my test case .STAsBinary() triples query times, so i was wondering that is there way to to just read WKB from database

Like

```
 SELECT ... geom_wkb from (select ... ,geom_wkb, geom ) where geom.filter(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-sqlserver/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/sqlserver/SQLServerDialect.java#L517) it looks like you need to set `Use native geometry serialization` to false to turn this off. I don't have an SQL Server to test against so I can't check to see if it is exposed in the GeoServer UI.

It may be worth trying the JTDS driver instead of the MS one as it is often much faster.

Comment: Tested, now it want geometry not byte[] type from database. But it  is much faster with it. I have to look that JTDS driver